# UITableView - Scroll to bottom before viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In case it's not obvious by the title, what I want should be simple, for the `tableView` to start scrolled all the way to the bottom when the users first sees it (**before he sees it, and without animations**).

So, I know that this has been answered a few times, but none of those solutions seem to work right now.
To give some context, I'm using Swift, autolayout and latest version of iOS as of today.

**Constraints**

There are some things I need to support:

1. load it before user sees it (without animations, obviously).
2. dynamic cell heights, i.e., their height is determined by a UILabel (like a messaging app - using autolayout in storyboard).
3. My `UITableView` is inside a `UIScrollView` (`UIScrollView` scrolls horizontally and `UITableView` scrolls vertically).
4. The `UITableView` is in a `childViewController`, i.e., I add it to the main `UIViewController` (which, for some reason, makes `viewWillAppear` not get called - `viewDidAppear` is still called).

I'll make a summary of what I tried:

**As for implementations:**

1. `tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: CGFloat.max`
2. `tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPathForLastItem, atScrollPosition: .Bottom, animated: false)`
3. 

```
    var contentOffset = tableView.contentOffset
    contentOffset.y = tableView.contentSize.height - tableView.bounds.size.height
    tableView.setContentOffset(contentOffset, animated: false)
```

4. 

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        // tried option 1., 2. and 3. here
    })
```

**As for places I've tried to call those implementations:**

1. `viewDidLoad`
2. `viewWillAppear`
3. `viewDidLayoutSubviews` (only the first time it's called, I use a property to track that)
4. `viewDidAppear` (even though this wouldn't give me what I want)
5. On my model's `didSet`

Before those I always called `tableView.reloadData`

**What I DON'T want to do:**

`tableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1)`

+

`cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1)`

(I'm assuming that if you think of suggesting this solution, it's because you know the hack I'm talking about. If you don't, then you won't be suggesting this, so you don't need to understand how it works)

One of the reasons why I don't want this one is because now I can't scroll to the top...

**Problems I've noticed:**

1. The `tableView`'s `contentSize` (as a `UIScrollView` subclass) changes when you scroll for the first time after it appeared. Yes, I meant `contentSize`, not `contentOffset`, and it changes more than once while you scroll. After you've scrolled through the entire `tableView` once, it doesn't change anymore.
2. Some people are saying it works for fewer cells (and to be honest, it was working for me at some point), so try it with at least 20 items.
3. `viewWillAppear` doesn't get called, but `viewDidAppear` does.

Any solutions (except for the one I mentioned I don't want) would be very much appreciated. Even hacky ones, as long as they don't break other stuff.

Just as a side note, `scrollToRowAtIndexPath...` does not scale, i.e., it is too slow if you have, say, 2000 items. So Ideally I'd prefer a solution that scales.

**EDITS AFTER ANSWERS:**

1. After @bsmith11's answer I tried:

   ```
   private var called = false
   override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
       super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

       if !called {
           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
               self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.tableView.bounds.height), animated: false)
           })
           called = true
       }
   }
   ```

   And it didn't work.

Comment: Try to implement it in func loadView() method, As docs say:  This method loads or creates a view and assigns it to the view property. .. You can override this method in order to create your views manually. If you choose to do so, assign the root view of your view hierarchy to the view property. The views you create should be unique instances and should not be shared with any other view controller object. Your custom implementation of this method should not call super.

Comment: I'll try and updated the question if it doesn't work, but wouldn't that be the same as `tableView.reloadData()` + any of the others? calling `tableView.reloadData()`should trigger `loadView()`.

Comment: @AlexKosyakov why did you remove your answer? Did you try it and it didn't work?

Comment: No, actually it works fine for me, and crashes without [super loadView], but there should not be this super call, did you try it in your project?

Comment: Could you formulate the answer again so that I know what exactly to try?

Comment: If your viewWillAppear method is not called, something is seriously broken. Fix that. It's pointless to try to get the scrolling right in that case.

Comment: Now _that_ is how you write a good question.

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz i've the same problem on my paged tableview. I understand the problem because cannot receive cell events anymore after i scroll to row programmatically at the beginning. Only after i adjust view with my finger fitting the screen, the events begins to works, or when i scroll on top. If a scroll on bottom didn't work. Have you found a solution? I'm getting crazy my this issue. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

In `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`, set the `.contentOffset` to `tableView.bounds.height`. You will need to kick this off in an async block to give the `tableView` time to load it's content.

`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { 
     self.tableView.setContentOffset(tableView.bounds.height, animated: false)
 }`

`viewDidLayoutSubviews()` can get called multiple times, so you probably want to make sure your code above only gets called once.

Comment: Isn't that the same as what I did with implementation 4. in place 3. ?

Comment: No, it looks like you were using:

`contentOffset.y = tableView.contentSize.height - tableView.bounds.size.height`

Comment: I'm assuming `tableView.bounds.height == tableView.bounds.size.height` == "size of windows" == 640. Correct? If so, then `tableView.bounds.height` won't scroll to the bottom, i.e., `tableView.bounds.height` is not proportional to the number of items/cells. (In any case, I will try it when I get home)

Comment: Also, between this (or any other value) and `CGFloat.max`, it wouldn't make much difference right? since any other value would be smaller than `CgFloat.max`.

Comment: Tried and it didn't work. I edited the answer, please check that this is what you meant.

Comment: Ahh, I misunderstood what you wanted. So you want to scroll the last cell off the screen? If you are using auto cell sizing, I don't think it's possible, since `tableView` doesn't know it's `contentSize`, since all the heights are dynamically calculated. If you manually calculate the sizes, then it should be possible

Comment: The thing is, if I manually calculate the size of each cell, it will probably be too slow when I have 2000 items.

Answer (score 1):

Just tried with below code it works fine.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

      myArray = [["Data": "1234567890", "Height": 44],["Data": "12345678901234567890", "Height": 88],["Data": "12345678901234567890", "Height": 88],["Data": "12345678901234567890", "Height": 88],["Data": "12345678901234567890", "Height": 88],["Data": "12345678901234567890", "Height": 88],["Data": "12345678901234567890", "Height": 88],["Data": "12345678901234567890", "Height": 88],["Data": "12345678901234567890", "Height": 88],["Data": "12345678901234567890", "Height": 88],["Data": "12345678901234567890", "Height": 88],["Data": "12345678901234567890", "Height": 88],["Data": "12345678901234567890", "Height": 88],["Data": "12345678901234567890", "Height": 88],["Data": "12345678901234567890", "Height": 88],["Data": "12345678901234567890", "Height": 88],["Data": "12345678901234567890", "Height": 88],["Data": "12345678901234567890", "Height": 88],["Data": "12345678901234567890", "Height": 88],["Data": "12345678901234567890", "Height": 88],["Data": "End of Table", "Height": 132]]

    let no = myArray.count-1

    let lastIndex = NSIndexPath(forRow: no, inSection: 0)

    table1.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(lastIndex, atScrollPosition: .Bottom, animated: true)

}
```

[Download sample code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7ooURy3zGWKaXJKdDB5LUxBLTA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I've edited my question to add the constraints I need that makes this impossible. But even when my `viewWillAppear` was working, I tried this and didn't work.

Comment: You can download sample code, i have just updated my answer. @RodrigoRuiz

Comment: I need dynamic cell heights based on autolayout, the `UITableView` inside a `UIScrollView` and the `UITableView` as a childViewController. I know that code works for a regular `UITableView` setup, but it's buggy for other more complex scenarios. I need something that always works.

Comment: Also, it's `animated: true`, I need it to be false, i.e., not animated

Comment: No matter you have autolayout and dynamic height for cell. scrollToRowAtIndexPath this will scrolldown to last row of table, you can make it animated false.

Comment: My `viewWillAppear` is not getting called. Should this same code work in `viewDidAppear`? If it should, I tried, and it didn't.

Comment: Is your viewWillAppear getting called after UITableView delegates ?

Answer (score 1):

```
private var called = false
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    if !called {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.tableView.bounds.height), animated: false)
        })
        called = true
    }
}
```

I tried this code with my UIScrollView. **And it works**. If I have `dispatch_async` removed it become not working.

**Swift 3 code**

```
private var called = false
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    if !called {
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.tableView.bounds.height), animated: false)})
        called = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add the following method to custom subclass.

```
 - (void)tableViewScrollToBottomAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
        NSInteger numberOfRows = [_tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0];
        if (numberOfRows) {
            [_tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:numberOfRows-1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:animated];
        }
    }
```

Calling `[self tableViewScrollToBottomAnimated:NO]` at the end of `viewDidAppear` works.
One concern is there Unfortunately, it also causes `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` to get called three times for every cell.

Comment: "Before those I always called tableView.reloadData"

Comment: Can you tell  me you have fetch data from where API or local?

Comment: My data is locally stored.

Comment: Please, try reading my entire question, it is loaded as I call `tableView.reloadData` (I also tried your solution in multiple places where it should be already loaded, like `viewDidAppear`). As for your second option, I already tried that too, as you can see in my implementation 1 and 3.

Comment: How is that different from calling the implementation directly in `viewDidAppear` (which didn't work for me)? And I don't have `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` implemented, I want my cells to be dynamically sized as explained in my question. Also, if you could avoid Objective-C it would be great (I don't want to propagate Objective-C culture).

Answer (score 0):

i had the exact same problem, after trying everything(same as you), this worked, the key is if you're using autolayout , you must write scrollToBottom code in viewDidLayoutSubviews

initialize scrollToBottom to true and then do this

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    // Scroll table view to the last row
    [self scrollToBottom];
}

-(void)scrollToBottom {
    if (shouldScrollToLastRow)
    {
        CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.tableView.contentSize.height - self.tableView.bounds.size.height);
        [self.tableView setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:NO];
    } }
```

doing this will ensure you're almost at the bottom of you're tableView but might not be at the very bottom as its impossible to know the exact bottom offset when you're at the top of the tableView, so after that we can implement scrollViewDidScroll

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView*)scrollView
{
    float scrollViewHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height;
    float scrollContentSizeHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height;
    float scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

    // if you're not at bottom then scroll to bottom
    if (!(scrollOffset + scrollViewHeight == scrollContentSizeHeight))
    {
        [self scrollToBottom];
    } else {
    // bottom reached now stop scrolling
        shouldScrollToLastRow = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also tried, but doesn't work with dynamic cell heights

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz my cell heights are dynamic too, i am building a chatClient to cell height vary a lot, i used autolayout to resize UITableViewCells and not the heightForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz edited my answer, please check if this works for you.

Comment: what you mean by "its impossible to know the exact bottom offset"?

Comment: And I do not want to introduce that extra `shouldScrollToLastRow` state (that's a very bad hack)... But I also tried your solution and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think that calling `[table setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, CGFLOAT_MAX)]` and `table.estimatedRowHeight = 50(change your value);` in ViewDidLoad is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

1. Uncheck "Automatic" tableview's properties ; row Height and Estimate

[image]

2. Add this code

   ```
   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

       super.viewWillAppear(animated)

       if scrollToBottomOnce == false {
           scrollToBottomOnce = true
           if self.items.count > 0 {
               self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude), animated: false)
           }
       }
   }
   ```